# How do I return a json value from an axios api request?

Tags: javascript, axios

I want to return a some information in a json format so I can assign variables to them. I'm using Axios to get some json info on movies but can't seem to assign a variable to the data, as I always get 'undefined' in the output. Any fixes?

Here's my code, as you can see I'm trying to return something from the function then assign a value to it.

```
function getMovie(movie){
    axios.get('http://www.omdbapi.com?t='+movie+'&apikey='+APIKEY)
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data);
            let info = response.data;
            return response.data;
        })
        .catch((error)=>{
            console.log(error);
        })
};

let movieInfo = getMovie('Dune');
console.log(movieInfo);
```

Comment: You sure api key working? 
What your console status? got `error log` or `undefined`?

Comment: it works fine with the console.log(response.data) statement, but when I try logging movieInfo, it returns undefined.

Comment: `getMovie('Dune').then(console.log)`. Also `return axios.get(...`

Comment: do you wrapper the ```let movieInfo = getMovie('Dune');
console.log(movieInfo);``` into a function?

Answer (score -1):

```
function getMovie(movie){
    let answer =  axios.get('http://www.omdbapi.com?t='+movie+'&apikey='+APIKEY)
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data);
            let info = response.data;
            return response.data;
        })
        .catch((error)=>{
            console.log(error);
        })
     return answer
};

let movieInfo = getMovie('Dune');
console.log(movieInfo);
```

Comment: `console.log(movieInfo);` will log the promise produced by `get`, not the result.

Comment: @danh pretty sure it will return the `response.data` into `answer` since the promise is solved by the `.then` block

Comment: The promise is returned immediately and assigned to `answer`.  That answer is returned immediately and assigned to `movieInfo`.  console log will log that promise.  Some time later, the the `then` block is executed, resolving the promise that was logged earlier.

Comment: @danh You are right :) . I am sad that I am wrong. I been using Axios for more than 1 year

Comment: You may have been using the more modern syntax, where you'd say `let answer = await get(...`. This nicer way to write it leaves one with the impression that async is solved -- that's why I think it's worthwhile to get the hang of promises using `.then`,  `.catch` and `Promise.all()`